# File targets to be prerequisites of PHONY targets order-only or not?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

The [Makefile style guide](http://clarkgrubb.com/makefile-style-guide#phony-targets) mentions that "No file targets should be prerequisites of .PHONY."

I assume you could reword that as "Don't declare file targets PHONY"?

To express dependencies, for the human reader as well as for Make, I guess you sometimes need file targets be prerequisites of PHONY targets.
Should those be order-only targets, then?
As far as I understand, in this case the only difference between order-only and not is if they appear in $^ or in $|, so it probably depends on what behavior you want in that matter, respectively which kind of dependency you want to express.

Am I correct here? (If there is no clear case for one or the other,) are there any reasons to choose one over the other (order-only or not)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I guess you sometimes need file targets be prerequisites of PHONY targets

Most of the time, in fact. Consider that "standard" stuff:

```
.PHONY: all
all: myprog other_stuff
myprog: $(OBJECTS)
    ...
```

But "Don't declare file targets PHONY / No file targets should be prerequisites of .PHONY" is a totally different thing. It means `.PHONY: myprog` is bad and should be avoided. The reason is that (1) it unconditionally triggers rebuild of `myprog` which is abnormal; (2) it could fool a human into thinking that `myprog` is "not a file".

If you need to force rebuild of `myprog` once you do `make -B myprog`. If it really needs to be rebuilt every time make runs, then you can do:

```
myprog: $(OBJECTS) FORCE
    ...
FORCE:;
```

Or something like that.

> As far as I understand, in this case the only difference between order-only and not is if they appear in $^ or in $|

The order-only prerequisites are rarely used GNU extension. There is no need to put them in just to show that "phony stuff" on the left side will be rebuilt anyway. So no one ever writes `all: | myprog`, although it would work as good as `all: myprog`.

Comment: Thanks, now that you mentioned FORCE I understand why one would consider declaring file targets PHONY.