# GNU make - enforcing dependency order for PHONY targets

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I have a Makefile as below, and I am concerned with the dependency order for `up-clean`:

```
.PHONY: up
up: down
    docker-compose up -d

.PHONY: up-clean
up-clean: down-clean up

.PHONY: down
down:
    docker-compose down

.PHONY: down-clean
down-clean:
    docker-compose down -v
```

Obviously it is important that in `up-clean: down-clean up`, `down-clean` **must** be executed before `up`. For ordinary make targets, the solution would be to add an entry, `up: down-clean`, but as these are PHONY targets, that would make `up` functionally equivalent to `up-clean`, removing volumes every time. Obviously, this is unacceptable.

In practice, GNU make respects the order of dependencies, but it does not guarantee it, and so is not entirely trustworthy, or with `-j` not trustworthy at all. What methods, if any, exist to ensure the order of execution of dependencies in this situation without changing the result of building other targets?

EDIT: Attempting to use [order-only prerequisites](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Prerequisite-Types.html) does not appear to work, possibly because of an interaction with `.PHONY`. Adding

```
up: | down-clean
```

Causes the execution log to be:

```sh
$ make up
docker-compose down
<...>
docker-compose down -v
Removing volume <...>
```

Which is what is supposed to happen for *normal* prerequisites, not order-only ones.

Comment: I can patch this over with `.NOTPARALLEL` so that it's *merely* 'not entirely trustworthy' even with `-j`, but I'd like to make it properly trustworthy.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56219367/18411863 mentions order-only prerequisites, but adding `up: | down-clean` seems to treat this as a normal prerequisite, despite being GNU Make 3.81.

Comment: There is some misunderstanding about what order-only means.  It doesn't mean that the prerequisite is only run if the target is run.  It means that make will try to build all the prerequisites just as it would normally, but the order-only prerequisite doesn't have any impact on whether the target is rebuilt or not (the prerequisite is ordered before the target, but doesn't make the target out-of-date).  Indeed, it's useless with PHONY targets since PHONY targets are always out of date.

Comment: That's not true - the docs specifically say *"to impose a specific ordering on the rules to be invoked without forcing the target to be updated if one of those rules is executed"*, and later when describing an example say *"the rule to create the objdir directory will be run, **if needed**"*.
Also, https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-make/2021-08/msg00010.html states that it is supposed to retain its order-only behavior even if phony - the attached diff adds ```+An order-only prerequisite marked as phony (@pxref{Phony Targets}) retains its
+order-only behavior.```

Comment: The "if needed" here means that if that target, by itself, is needed (in other words, if the directory doesn't exist).  It doesn't mean if the target that lists the directory as order only prerequisite is not needed.  The ONLY difference between order-only and not is that after all prerequisites (order only and not) are complete, when make is determining if the target is out of date with respect to the prerequisites, it will ignore the order-only prerequisites during that calculation.

Comment: But, phony targets are always rebuilt regardless of their prerequisites.  The doc clarification is that if you have a normal target which is order-only on a phony prerequisite, then the normal target is not rebuilt.  But you don't have that: you have a phony target.  Because the target is phony, it is always rebuilt regardless of what prerequisites may or may not have been rebuilt.

Comment: @MadScientist I use to replace _order-only_ mentally with _ensure-existence, ignore-timestamp_ when thinking about order-only prerequisites - is this a valid picture?

Comment: As I said above, a regular prerequisite is built, then if its timestamp is newer than the target the target is built.  The only difference between a regular prerequisite and an order-only prerequisite is that the timestamp of the order-only prerequisite is not considered when deciding if the target should be rebuilt.  In all other ways, they are identical to regular prerequisites.  Whatever terminology helps you remember that, is valid IMO.

Answer (score 3):

The simplest answer is to use recursive invocations of make:

```
up-clean:
        $(MAKE) down-clean
        $(MAKE) up
```

Answer (score 1):

Starting with [GNU make 4.4](https://lwn.net/Articles/913253/) you can explicitly serialize your prerequisites with the `.WAIT` pseudo-target, e.g.,

```
.PHONY: up-clean
up-clean: down-clean .WAIT up
```

Before 4.4, the GNU Make documentation wasn't making any commitments about the order or execution to enable parallel execution. However, any [POSIX-compliant](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/make.html) implementation of make (emphasis mine)

> ... shall treat all prerequisites as targets themselves and recursively ensure that they are up-to-date, processing them **in the order in which they appear in the rule**. The make utility shall use the modification times of files to determine whether the corresponding targets are out-of-date.

Of course, in the parallel mode, GNU make can't be fully compliant with this requirement.

But, the 4.4 release also adds the `--shuffle` option, and from the [research made by the implementor of this option](https://trofi.github.io/posts/238-new-make-shuffle-mode.html), it is evident that the only source of non-determinism is the `-j` option and the parallel mode of execution, which is also witnessed by the contents of the patch and the tests, which were reviewed by other members of the GNU make project.

Therefore, in version prior to 4.4, we can safely assume that the prerequisites are executed strictly in the order in which they are specified, from left to right, as long as make is executed in non-parallel mode. In versions before 4.4, we can disable parallelism with the `.NOTPARALLEL` pseudo target, just add it to your file, e.g.,

```
.NOTPARALLEL: # ensures that all deps are executed strictly in order

.PHONY: up
up: down
    docker-compose up -d

.PHONY: up-clean
up-clean: down-clean up

.PHONY: down
down:
    docker-compose down

.PHONY: down-clean
down-clean:
    docker-compose down -v
```

Notice also, that `--shuffle` [respects](https://trofi.github.io/posts/249-an-update-on-make-shuffle.html) the presence of the `.NOTPARALLEL` target, which corroborates our hypothesis the order could be different from the syntactic order only because of the parallel execution.

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative would be to model `up-clean` on `up` instead of making the latter a prerequisite for the former:

```
.PHONY: up
up: down
    docker-compose up -d

.PHONY: up-clean
up-clean: down-clean
    docker-compose up -d
```

If you want to make that a little DRYer, you could factor out the `docker-compose` command to a variable:

```
UP_COMMAND = docker-compose up -d

.PHONY: up
up: down
    $(UP_COMMAND)

.PHONY: up-clean
up-clean: down-clean
    $(UP_COMMAND)
```